# JIRA Python Setting Labels

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I am trying to set the labels field for a JIRA ticket in Python using the jira-python API.

With a valid JIRA issue object, created with `issue = jira.issue(jira_ticket)`, I have tried the following:

- `issue.update(labels='AAA')`: gives a `not on the appropriate screen` error as below.
- `issue.update(fields={'labels':'AAA'})`: also gives a `not on the appropriate screen` error as below.
- `issue.fields.labels.append(u'AAA')`: does not produce an error, but does not update field. I guess it updates the issue object, but doesn't push back to JIRA server.

I seem to always receive the error:

```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://someserver/rest/api/2/issue/nnnnnn
text: Field 'labels' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
```

This is the same error as this post, [Python - JIRA - Modify Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855906/python-jira-modify-labels), but for different reasons - namely, labels are not turned off here, and I can set them with the web interface: See [Image: JIRA Labels Added in Web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfANJ.png) and [Image: updated JIRA issue with Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx1n4.png).

If I dump out the raw fields for the issue in question, having added labels to it using the Web UI as above, then I can see the labels in the Python JIRA Issue object:

`Field: 'labels', Value: ['StackOverflow', 'TAGTHATICANSEARCHFOR']`

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging around for an answer, it seems there is an ongoing problem with this.

It appears that I need to access labels manager to check issue labels and modify labels: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-add-a-Label-with-Java-Rest-API/qaq-p/560837

There's an issue posted with Atlassian - vote it up: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JRJC-109

Hopefully this helps someone if they find this post.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a label, you can follow [this example](https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html):

```py
# Or modify the List of existing labels. The new label is unicode with no
# spaces
issue.fields.labels.append("new_text")
issue.update(fields={"labels": issue.fields.labels})
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in many ways and the one that worked was passing the labels as an array:

in this way:

```
issue.update(fields={"labels":['AAA']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Judged from the error message, the "labels" field is not on the edit screen of your target issue.

Refer to the JIRA documentation to get a deeper understanding of screens in JIRA: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/defining-a-screen-802592587.html

Comment: Yes, so it would seem; However, given that I can actually edit it on the target issue using the WebUI that would suggest it should be doable? I also have sufficient permissions.